How to develop with future and devtools::load_all(".")
I am trying to develop a R package that calls functions in an asynchronous way using future::future. Here is a dummy example:
library(future)
plan(multisession)

test_fun <- function(str) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  cat(str)
}

test_future <- function() {
  future({test_fun("test")})
}

Calling the function works fine as expected
> f <- test_future()
> value(f)
# test

Nevertheless, if I put these functions in a package structure and load them (for testing) with devtools::load_all(".") I get an error upon calling the test_future function.
> devtools::load_all(".")
# ℹ Loading

> f <- test_future()
> value(f)
Error in test_fun("test") : could not find function "test_fun"

I guess its has something to do with the issue that the namespace environment is not available for the future process, but I do not understand how to come around this.
In the installed package it works fine, but I don't understand how to test and develop using my normal workflow : implement ➡ load_all ➡ test

For me it works with the following (relevant) files and the described workflow:
R/future.R
test_fun <- function(str) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  cat(str)
}

#' Test Future
#'
#' @return Nothing
#' @export
test_future <- function() {
  future::future({
    test_fun("test")
  })
}

Workflow

In RStudio I configured the project to use Roxygen docs:


I press Ctrl-Shift-D to generate the docs, most notably this NAMESPACE file:
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(test_future)


I load the library via Ctrl-Shift-L

I run
f <- test_future()
future::value(f)
# test



As you can see, everthing works smoothly. For all it matters, I am using RStudio 2024.04.2 and devtools_2.4.5
